# Is there any way to recover drooped/folded leaves?

Tags: leaves, plant-recommendations, snake-plants

My snake plant is drooping because of the lack of sunlight. I'm going to revive it by moving the pot, but do I have to cut very folded/drooped leaves? They are bent from the middle of the leaf. Any way to recover those leaves without cutting them? I currently use a wood stand for keeping them upward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bent/folded leaves can't be recovered on a snake plant. It is best to cut them either where the fold is or to cut the entire leaf. Cutting only the folded part will result in a not so aesthetic look, but the plant will grow new leaves faster because the partially cut leaves can still perform phosynthesis.